# javascript link isn't working on click; function works when page loads

Tags: javascript, function, random, shuffle

```
var randomNumber

// generate the random numbers based on the length of the image array
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * topImages.length);

function shuffleTop(){
  document.getElementById("topImage").src = topImages[randomNumber];
};

$("p a#shuffle").click(shuffleTop());
```

**This is my link in my source code:**

```
<p><a href="#" id="shuffle">SHUFFLE</a></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are running the function and what it is returning is being assigned to the cliek. You are not assigning a reference to the function `shuffleTop`.

```
$("p a#shuffle").click(shuffleTop());
```

needs to be

```
$("p a#shuffle").click(shuffleTop);
```

and you only generate the number once, move the random number generator inside.

```
function shuffleTop(){
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * topImages.length);
  document.getElementById("topImage").src = topImages[randomNumber];
};
```

Comment: Doy, thank you! Now the next problem is that it only runs once, then i have to reload the page for it to work again.

Comment: To clarify: the thing that you're assigning to the click event is what gets returned by shuffleTop (eg, nothing), and not shuffleTop itself.

Comment: because the random number is outside.

Comment: ohmygod man thank you so much, i've been stuck on this for 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a function callback to your click event:

```
$("p a#shuffle").click(shuffleTop);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery might as well use jQuery to set the image src.

```
$("#topImage").attr("src",topImages[randomNumber]);
```

I assume that topImages[randomNumber] already contains a url to an image *relative* to the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

First, why you use pure js, if you have jQuery?

```
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * topImages.length);
function shuffleTop(){
  $("#topImage").attr('src', topImages[randomNumber]);
};
$("p a#shuffle").on('click', shuffleTop); // i re-write this to call function.
```

It has to be worked